# validate dropdown in mvc5

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having trouble in attempting to validate that a value has been chosen from a dropdown as follows:

Please Select Type
                    Keypad
                    Bill Pay

I have added the following details as part of my model:

```
[Required]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 10)]
    public string AccountType { get; set; }
```

When I post the form it is not highlighting the account type as not being filled out correctly. Any ideas why? I thought that the minimum length would have caught this

Answer (score 0):

I will show validation for country below.

Model:

```
public class CountryModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Country Required.")]
    public int SelectedCountryId { get; set; }
    public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList Countries { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(CountryModel model)
    {
        if (model.Countries == null)
        {
            model.Countries = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Text= "India", Value = "1" },
                new SelectListItem() { Text= "Australia", Value = "2"}
            },"Value","Text");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

My View:

```
@model MVCControls.Models.CountryModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }
<h2>Dropdownlist Validation</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.Label("Country")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedCountryId,Model.Countries,     "..Select..")
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Country is required.");
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" />
}
```

Hope this helps